# How to change Hive Database to Oracle Database as Primary Database in Kylo?

Tags: kylo

I'm kylo platform for my tool. I need the Oracle database instead of the hive database on the kylo platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Kylo to land data in Oracle as the destination database instead of Hive.The ([data ingest template](https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/blob/master/samples/templates/nifi-1.0/data_ingest.zip)) that comes with Kylo uses Hive by default. Some features in Kylo also depend on Hive (e.g. Validation, Profiling).

However, you can create your custom template in NiFi that uses Oracle as the destination database. NiFi has some processors that can help you design your template. One example is [PutSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/index.html) processor. All available processors are documented [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html).

The steps to use this flow via Kylo are:

1. Create the template in NiFi and test that it works.
2. Register the template in Kylo and configure properties that should be exposed to a feed creator.
3. Create a feed out of the registered template and provide feed-specific values for the properties exposed in step 2.
4. Schedule the feed to run on a cron or time-based schedule. Kylo will show feed executions via the Operations Manager UI.

Kylo has some useful [video tutorials](https://kylo.io/tutorials.html) that can help you with configuring the above steps (template registration, feed creation, feed monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

The Kylo dependencies page currently only lists MySQL, PostgreSQL, and MS SQL as supported databases: http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/Dependencies.html#kylo-stack-dependencies

You can try using Oracle by setting the following properties appropriately:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.maxActive=30
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

You will also need to download the Oracle JDBC driver and install it to /opt/kylo/kylo-services/plugin/. There's more information in the Kylo docs:
http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/KyloApplicationProperties.html#kylo